# LINQ to SQL returns wrong results

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've been trying to solve this for the entire day.. :-(

I'm Using C# with MSSQL and querying via LINQ

I have a collection stored in `studWithTuiDisc` variable, It contains the following data (shown in the link below)

[image]
<sub>(source: [secompeusc.com](http://secompeusc.com/images/orig.png))</sub>

When using this variable as reference for other LINQ Statements the results are very off, prior to this post I performed experiments to check if it really wasn't my fault that incorrect results were returned:

(1) I tried to iterate through `studWithTuiDisc` and then checking the relationship only in the `select clause` since I'm sure that this will return the desired output (see below)
Code:

```
var xxx = (from a in studWithTuiDisc  
           select new 
           { 
             please = a.StudentId, 
             help = _conn.EEnrolledSubjects
                    .Where(m => m.StudentId == a.StudentId)
                    .Select(m => m.StudentId)
                    .FirstOrDefault() 
           }).Distinct();
```

Output:
[image: Control Experiment Output]
<sub>(source: [secompeusc.com](http://secompeusc.com/images/xxx.png))</sub>

**As we can see the `studWithTuiDisc` values are the only values contained in `xxx`**

(2) Now I tried the approach that gave me a lot of headaches (see below)
Code:

```
var zzz = (from a in studWithTuiDisc
           join b in _conn.EEnrolledSubjects on a.StudentId equals b.StudentId
           select new { please = a.StudentId, help = b.StudentId }).Distinct();
```

or

```
var zzz = (from a in studWithTuiDisc
           from b in _conn.EEnrolledSubjects
           where a.StudentId == b.StudentId
           select new { please = a.StudentId, help = b.StudentId }).Distinct();
```

Output:
[image: Experiment Output]
<sub>(source: [secompeusc.com](http://secompeusc.com/images/zzz.png))</sub>

**Given that we already know the values in `studWithTuiDisc` and since we used it as filter for `_conn.EEnrolledSubjects` we should be expecting results that are in `studWithTuiDisc` but looking at the screen shots, LINQ is not returning the proper results.**

What am I doing wrong?
Has anyone experienced something like this before?
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe better to write down and format code and output rather then post a number of screenshots?

Comment: Omg, I find the queries so difficult to read with this weird naming. "Stud With Tui Disc" ?!?

Comment: @abatishchev It is the actual code taken directly from the program

Comment: Have you override Equals on your entity objects?

Comment: @Phill Sorry about that, its short for Students With Tuition Fee Discount

Comment: @Tomas Voracek nope, no overrides

Comment: @abatishchev LINQ to SQL

Comment: @LINQ Newbee: Please write code as text not as image!

Comment: @abatishchev the code is text, Check code under the CODE: lable, wait it edit the post to make it in bold (strong) so that its easier for you to see

Comment: @abatishchev Sorry it seems I'm not able to edit any more since there are images, and I'm not allowed to post images. Just check codes under the CODE: label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what is generated/sent to SQL Server by using [DataContext.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx), or SQL Profiler. I think that your queries will be different.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not explain the output:  
it is correct, it should be new { please = a.StudentId, help = b.StudentId }.  please --> represents the StudentId from studWithTuiDisc.  help ----> represents the StudentId from _conn.EEnrolledSubjects  
  
The topic here really is why does StudentId's not included in  studWithTuiDisc appear in the result

Comment: @LINQ Newbee: You can use tilde to highlight `code in comments`

Comment: Yes, it is showing a rather odd generated SQL, now I can take it from here.  Thanks so much.